# Can I "extend" a method, or call a method inside of another one?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

*I am working on a game that's played on a chess like board with only pawns. A pawn can move, or take an opponents piece. To move it goes one tile forward, to take it goes one tile forward and one to the side.
As the move action is also part of every take action I was wondering if I can somehow combine those two. I tried to integrate the move method in my take method, but it didn't work, supposedly because the method doesn't know which piece it is associated with.
Both methods alter the attributes (x-coordinate and y-coordinate) of my piece to mark it's location on the board.
Can I do it in some other way?

````
    /*
     * move action
     * differentiates between Black and White pieces, so both use the same method to move
     */
    public void move() {

        switch(color) {
        case "White":
            this.yCo = this.yCo+1;
            break;
        case "Black":
            this.yCo = this.yCo-1; 
            break;
        }

    }

    /*
     * take action
     * moves one tile forward and one tile to either left or right and removes an opponents piece on that tile
     */
    public void takeRight() {
        
        this.move();
        
        this.xCo = this.xCo+1;

    }
```*
````

Comment: Yes, it's fine to call one method from within another. What *exactly* to you mean by "supposedly because the method doesn't know which piece it is associated with"? What exactly happened when you tried the code you've posted?

Comment: @JonSkeet Actually I fixed that code, as my switch statement missed a break. But when I compile it like in my example the move() inside of take() is just skipped.

Comment: I think that's *highly* unlikely, I think it's much more likely that you've misdiagnosed the problem. We can't really tell without more information though - ideally a [mcve].

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void move(int xShift) {
    switch(color) {
        case "White":
            this.yCo = this.yCo+1;
            break;
        case "Black":
            this.yCo = this.yCo-1; 
            break;
    }
    this.xCo += xShift;
}
```

`this.xCo += xShift` is short for `this.xCo = this.xCo + xShift`. You may also remove the dedundant this